# NavigationView. Blank screen

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview

I develop first SwiftUI app.
Can't manage with this problem. NavigationView returns empty space instead of my view.

```
struct Home: View {
    @SwiftyUserDefault(keyPath: \.gridEnabled) var gridEnabled
    @State private var grid = false
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var openAbout: Int? = nil

    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
        UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "ColorPrimaryDark")
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let menuView = MenuView(onMenuSelected: {
            index in
            print("Selected: \(index)")
            if index == 3{
                self.openAbout = 10
                return
            }
            self.selectedIndex = index
        })
        
        return
                NavigationView{
                    ZStack{
                        NavigationLink(destination: About().navigationBarTitle(Text("About the app"), displayMode: .inline), tag: 10, selection: self.$openAbout) {
                          EmptyView()
                            }.hidden()
                        TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
                            SoundList(grid: self.grid)
                            .tabItem {
                                    Image("SoundIcon").renderingMode(.template)
                                    Text("All sounds")
                            }
                            .tag(0)
                            SoundList(grid: self.grid, popular: true)
                            .tabItem {
                                    Image("PopularIcon").renderingMode(.template)
                                Text("Popular")
                            }
                            .tag(1)
                            Favorite()
                            .tabItem {
                                    Image("FavoriteIcon").renderingMode(.template)
                                    Text("Favorite")
                                }
                        .tag(2)
                        
                        }            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle()).accentColor(Color("ColorAccent"))
                        .navigationBarTitle(Text("SleepGo"), displayMode: .inline).navigationBarColor(.clear).navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                            menuView.toggle()

                        }, label: {Image("MenuIcon")}), trailing: Button(action: {
                            self.gridEnabled = !self.gridEnabled
                            self.grid = self.gridEnabled
                        }, label: {Image(self.grid ? "GridIcon" : "ListIcon")})).background(Image("Background2").resizable().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                    }
                    menuView
                }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
}
```

**Test on iOS 13.1.2 (iPhone 7).**
Here I see blank screen inside NavigationView.

**Test on iOS 13.7 (iPhone 11)**
Here is ok. Displayed normally.

How to fix it?

Comment: Try to break Home content on separated small subviews and removing by one find which one cause the issue.

Comment: Make sure the storyboard is set to the same device that you are testing on.  iPhone 7 has a smaller screen than iPhone 11.  If the storyboard is laying out your UI on an iPhone 11, and the simulator is running an iPhone 7, then some of the UI elements will be drawn off screen.